# Acumatica capture event for INSiteStatus qtyAvail not triggering

Tags: events, acumatica

I am trying to run some code whenever the qtyAvail changes for a stock item.  I have added code in an extension to InventoryItemMaint to both INSiteStatus and INSiteStatusSummary for the event fieldupdated for the field qtyAvail, but I cannot get my code to execute.

Any suggestions about the right way to capture that field change?

```
public class InventoryItemMaint_Extension : PXGraphExtension<InventoryItemMaint>

void _(Events.FieldUpdated<INSiteStatusSummary, INSiteStatusSummary.qtyAvail> e){
  //My Code
}

void _(Events.FieldUpdated<INSiteStatus, INSiteStatus.qtyAvail> e){
  //My Code
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't explain in your ticket when qtyAvail will change which is a key element to your problem.  Going out on a limb, I'm going to assume you are thinking of this like a Database trigger that fires whenever the value changes, but that is not the case.
Events are driven by actions taken by one of a graph's (InventoryItemMaint) caches.   I don't think there is any operation in Inventory Item Maintenance that changes the qtyAvail for either of these DACs, therefore the qtyavail field will not be updated in a cache for this graph and the event you've created won't fire.

Comment: Thanks.  I guess I understand what you are saying.  So, what I need to do is pick specific activities that change the Qty, and then add events to those graphs?  The problem is that there are lots of different things that can change the stock Qty.  Should I just try to find all the common cases and add code to those?

Comment: Hey Shane.  It's hard to say without knowing the problem you're trying to solve, but yes I think that's probably the only way you'll be able to solve the problem via the Event Model.

Comment: Thanks Patrick.  I have gone back to the customer and explained that I needed to catch something from specific actions in the system.  They advised that they only really need it for the PO receipt release and the stock adjustment release.  So I have overridden those actions.  To get it to work, I had to replace the original action with it's full code modified to add my little piece.  But it all works, so it is all good.

Thanks again for your help.